# Get json data from microsoft sql server and store in variable to use in vuejs v-for attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, vue.js

I am developing a full stack application. And my front-end development is ready. I am using vuejs to display array on screen. And now I need to get that array from sql server using nodejs. I really dont know about asynchronous functions, http requests and tons of server based knowledges. Just wanted to get a array without any knowledge exploring.

It is my node module which is set for get data or insert data into mssql server.

```
var dbConfig = {

    server: "localhost\\MSSQLSERVER",
    database: "sample",
    user: 'sa',
    password:'deegii2001060108',
    port: 1433
};
var result;

exports.dbcontext=function(engine, config){

    const sql = require('mssql')
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var conn = sql.connect(config, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                sql.query(engine, function(err, recordsets,returnValue, affected) {
                    if(err) {
                        reject(error);
                    } else {
                        result = recordsets;
                        resolve(recordsets);
                        conn.close();
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
}


exports.dbcontext('select * from tblGender', dbConfig).then(recordset=>{console.log(recordset)});
console.log('result',result);
```

in console:

```
result undefined

{ 
     recordsets: [ [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] ],

     recordset:[ 

     { id: 1, gender: 'male' },

     { id: 2, gender: 'female' },

     { id: 3, gender: 'unknown' },

     { id: 4, gender: 'aertq' },

     { id: 5, gender: 'from vscode' } ],

     output: {},

     rowsAffected: [ 5 ] } //i wanted to store recordset into my global result var outside of function
}
```

```
exports.dbcontext(... //connection function

result = recordsets; /*the result variable is not changed but i want to 
store recordsets in global variable outside of the function*/

...}

//Unexpected result:
console.log(result) // undefined
//Expected result:
console.log(result) // an array consists of objects
```

Answer (score 0):

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

```
var sql = require("mssql");

// config for your database
var config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'deegii2001060108',
    server: 'localhost\\MSSQLSERVER', 
    database: 'sample' 
};

// connect to your database
sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query('select * from tblGender', function (err, result) {

        if (err) console.log(err)

        // send records as a response
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var result;

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost\\MSSQLSERVER",
    user: "sa",
    password: "deegii2001060108",
    database: "sample"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("select * from tblGender", function (err, data, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        result = data;
    });
    console.log(json.stringify(result));
});
```